# Search elements from ArrayList with custom class and change color for it

Tags: java, android, class, search, arraylist

**ItemClass for ArrayList**

```
public class ItemClass {
...
    private String mNomenclatureBrand;
...
    public ItemClass(... String NomenclatureBrand ...) {
        ...
        mNomenclatureBrand = NomenclatureBrand;
        ...
    }
    ...
    public String getNomeclatureBrand() {
        return mNomenclatureBrand;
    }
    ...
}
```

**ArrayList nomenclatureList**

```
 nomenclatureList.add(new ItemClass(
                ...
                "Alex",
                ...
 nomenclatureList.add(new ItemClass(
                ...
                "Gustiyar",
                ...
```

For search "Alex" (`getNomeclatureBrand`) in this `ArrayList` I use

```
for (ItemClass d : nomenclatureList) {
    if (d.getNomeclatureBrand() != null && d.getNomeclatureBrand().equals("Alex")) {
        int size = nomenclatureList.size();
        Toast.makeText(this, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        TextView nomenclarureBrand = findViewById(R.id.nomenclatureBrand);
        nomenclarureBrand.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
}
```

But app crash in

```
nomenclarureBrand.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: What does "crash" mean? Is there any error message given?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setBackgroundColor(int)' on a null object reference
        at ru.renna.amkk.ItemsListMK.onCreate(ItemsListMK.java:145)

Comment: But this TextView is not null, it contains barnd-information from getNomeclatureBrand.

Comment: Well, if it really is not null, then your JVM is completely broken. Have you checked what `nomenclarureBrand` really contains at the time the app crashes?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that nomenclatureBrand is contain "Alex" (from debug).